# element is invalid - The value '' is invalid according to its datatype 'Decimal'

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xsd

I have a .NET console application where I am testing a third party `soap web service`. Every time I ran this console application I was getting an error and exception handling was not telling me much in Visual Studio. It simply was telling me that 'the input was not in the correct format'. So, I decided to investigate the xml returned and the xsd by using Stylus and .NET Parser to parse the data. .NET Parser returned this error back:

```
KOCSU1' element is invalid - The value '' is invalid according to its datatype 'Decimal' - The string '' is not a valid Decimal value.
```

And the element has not value in the returned xml:

and in the XSD this element is specified as Decimal Data type:

```
  <xsd:element name="KOCSU1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
  <xsd:simpleType>
      <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal"/>
   </xsd:simpleType>
   </xsd:element>
```

So far I understand the problem as the parser is expecting a Decimal value rather than an empty string.

Is it possible to access the .NET parser and tell it that if the element is empty just ignore it?
How can I check in code for empty elements which are decimal datatypes and ignore them?

Comment: The problem lies with the SOAP service as it's not returning data that complies with the xsd. Are you able to log a issue with the provider to have them fix either the xsd or the data?

Comment: Alternatively, if you are able to control the xsd used, you could provide your own that allows for `nil` values. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876049/create-an-xsd-optional-decimal-element-with-restrictions for advice on how to handle an optional decimal with a restriction.

Comment: @David, I will give the link a try.
To answer the first question, I am going to ask them if they can change it, but I am not sure if they are going to do that.